# next prev function using JavaScript/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the next function that i learn from other's post and i wonder how to do the prev function.

any idea guys? Different approach are welcome as well.

```
function next() {
    var pElems = document.querySelectorAll('#Pages>div');
    for (var i = 0; i < pElems.length; i++) {
        if (pElems[i].style.display !== 'none') {
            pElems[i].style.display = 'none';
            if (i === pElems.length - 1) {
                pElems[0].style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                pElems[i + 1].style.display = 'block';
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly the same, but reverse the array. Or start at the end of the array and do i-- until it's 0. Or use `i == pElems.lenghth + 1` in combination with `pElems[i - 1].style.display` etc. So may possibilities, just play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current function steps one element forward: `pElems[i + 1]`, so to go backwards you could just step one backwards `pElems[i - 1]` and then you have to handle the case of reaching the first element and jump to the end, something like this should do it:

```
function prev() {
    var pElems = document.querySelectorAll('#Pages>div');
    for (var i = 0; i < pElems.length; i++) {
        if (pElems[i].style.display !== 'none') {
            pElems[i].style.display = 'none';
            if (i === 0) {
                pElems[pElems.length].style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                pElems[i - 1].style.display = 'block';
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```